# No support for zipping multiple Flows in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was really surprised when we were trying to move away from RxJ to kotlin Flows that there isn't any facility to zip multiple flows.

```
val flow1= (1..3).asFlow().onEach {delay(1000)}
val flow2= (1..3).asFlow().onEach {delay(2000)}
val flow3= (1..3).asFlow().onEach {delay(3000)}
```

I was looking for a Rx styled Flow.zip(flow1,flow2,flow3) however I failed to find any such facility.

What is strange to me that I didn't find many questions asking what I am asking here on stack or in any Kotlin Flows tutorial .

This makes me think that I must be doing something wrong , and that there might be an alternate facility to zip multiple flows.

Any hints ?

Comment: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html

Comment: Boris you didn't read my query closely I guess

Comment: maybe [combine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html)? (top-level functions)

Comment: Do you mean more than two flows? The `zip` function Boris linked does the same thing as Rx's zip, although it only works with two items. I'm not sure what you're getting at when you say they didn't read carefully. `combine` does something different than zipping. Zipping emits only one combined item for each item emitted by the slowest source. Combining emits a combined item for every item emitted by any source once they've all emitted at least once.

Comment: The coroutines standard library includes a minimal set of operators for complying with reactive programming. I don't know if they intend to add more detailed operators later, but they've stated that the current philosophy is to keep it minimal in the core library.

Comment: hey TenFour.  I need to zip more than 2 flows as I have shown by code in the question . I have three flows. I do understand there is a zip for 2, I need for 2 or more ,just as it was in RxJ

Comment: @IR42 combine is not the same as zip .

Comment: If you can zip two you can zip n.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own on top of `zip` for two flows

```
inline fun <A, B, C, D> Flow<A>.zip(
    flowB: Flow<B>,
    flowC: Flow<C>,
    crossinline f: (A, B, C) -> D
): Flow<D> =
    zip(flowB, ::Pair).zip(flowC) { (a, b), c -> f(a, b, c) }
```

Usage:

```
suspend fun main() {
    val one = flowOf(0, 1, 2, 3)
    val two = flowOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
    val three = flowOf(5.0, 6.0, 7.0)

    one.zip(two, three, ::Triple).collect(::print)
    // prints (0, a, 5.0)(1, b, 6.0)(2, c, 7.0)

}
```

Probably not as efficient as a direct implementation but depending on your use case it might be good enough.

Comment: Would you mind providing a more general solution for n flows?

Comment: A more general solution would be this: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/e7ddb2df918f46cb9f5ab3c9d7d7c1ff5f68b73f/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/internal/Combine.kt#L18

but it's less type-safe which I assume it's why it's `internal`.

You have to write one function per arity (parameter count), it's not possible to generalize further without a compiler plugin.